# Bug, switch state of boolean field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using https://gorails.com/forum/switch-state-of-boolean-field as a guide toggle a boolean value. I'm using a partial to display all the objects but only the first object toggles the boolean value. Also, the ajax is not working, I have to refresh the page to show the new boolean value.

Here is posts_controller:

```
def toggle_confirm

respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
end

    @post = Post.find_by(params[:id])
    @post.toggle!(:confirm)

end
```

Here is the views/shared/_received_feed partial:

```
<ol class="posts">
<% @received_feed.each do |feed| %>
    <%= render feed %>

    <%= link_to "#{ feed.confirm ? 'Confirmed' : 'Disabled' }", toggle_confirm_post_path(feed), method: :patch, remote: :true, class: "btn btn-xs btn-#{ feed.confirm ? 'success' : 'warning' }"  %>

<% end %>
</ol>
```

Here is the views/toggle_confirm.js.erb:

```
console.log(<%= @post.confirm %>);
<% if @post.confirm == true %>
    $(".post-<%= @post.id %> > 
        a").html('3Confirmed').removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-success')
<% else %>
    $(".post-<%= @post.id %> > a").html('Not 
        Confirmed').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning')
<% end %>
$("#post-status-<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= 
    @post.confirm %>")
```

Here is the partial for displaying each post views/posts/_posts:

```
<li id="post-<%= post.id %>">

  <span class="user"><%= post.sender.name %></span>
  <br>
  <span class="image"><%= image_tag post.sender.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
</span>
  <br>

  <span class="note"><%= post.note %></span>
  <br>

</li>
```

Comment: share the partial's code that renders each feed. And what do you mean by "but only the first object toggles the boolean value" ?, are you expecting to change the flag of many records in the same request ?, or are you saying that only the first time you click on a link it works ? and the second click doesn't ?

Comment: hey @fanta. Thanks for your response. I added the partial that renders each feed. So when I click on the disabled button to change the boolean value, only the first feed changes value. So if I have multiple feed items, all the feed item's button to change the boolean value only changes the boolean value of the first feed. It's very odd. Hope this clarify things, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: ok, so, first thing, why do you have `@post = Post.find_by(params[:id])` and `@post.toggle!(:confirm)` after the `respond_to` block ?, they should be before that block. Next, you have in your `_posts` template: `<li id="post-<%= post.id %>">`, and in your `toggle_confirm.js.erb` code you use `$(".post-<%= @post.id %>...` to find the element you want to update. If you notice, you're using `.post-` in the `js.erb` file whereas in your template you use: `<li id="post-<%=`, change your `js.erb` to use `$("#post-...`, it's an id not a class.